# Replace value in yaml file using yq

Tags: shell, yaml

I am using yq version 4.34.1 in powershell.

I try to replace the value of `.spec.source.targetRevision` in `target.yaml` with the newer value from a variable `$newTargetRevision`. So, what I am doing now is as follows.

```
$newTargetRevision = "v1.1.1-1"
yq -i '.spec.source.targetRevision = "$newTargetRevision"' target.yaml
```

What I have got is as follows.

```
spec:
  source:
    targetRevision: &default $newTargetRevision
```

I expect to get:-

```
spec:
  source:
    targetRevision: &default v1.1.1-1
```

I also tried removing double quotes from `$newTargetRevision` as follows, but the value in the yaml file is not updated at all.

```
yq -i '.spec.source.targetRevision = $newTargetRevision' target.yaml
```

I try many things but without success. Can you please suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are expecting the shell to expand the variable to its value within a single-quoted string, which is something that a Unix shells will not do.  On top of that, you are assuming that the variable's value does not contain certain specific characters, such as double quotes.

To properly insert (not inject) a shell variable's value into a YAML document using Mike Farah's `yq` utility, you use `env()` to read the variable's value from the environment:

```bash
newrevision=$newTargetRevision \
yq -i '.spec.source.targetRevision = env(newrevision)' target.yaml
```

This sets the environment variable `newrevision` to the value of the `newTargetRevision` variable and then modifies the correct place within the document in an in-place edit. You could also have exported the `newTargetRevision` variable, and used its name with `env()`.

Testing:

```bash
$ cat target.yaml
spec:
  source:
    targetRevision: &default v1.0
```

```bash
$ newTargetRevision='v1.1 "kangaroo"'
$ newrevision=$newTargetRevision yq -i '.spec.source.targetRevision = env(newrevision)' target.yaml
```

```bash
$ cat target.yaml
spec:
  source:
    targetRevision: &default v1.1 "kangaroo"
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally figure that out. The following works nicely in powershell.

```
yq -i ".spec.source.targetRevision = `"${newTargetRevision}`"" target.yaml
```

Comment: I don't know Powershell at all, but does this not leave the variable _unquoted_?

Comment: To my surprise as well, it does leave the value of this variable unquoted. So, I do not know if the person who votes this answer down has even tested that before voting down.